# laravel5 form not displayed on browser

Tags: forms, view, laravel-5

My `register.blade.php` file -

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'register'))}}
        {{ Form::label('email','Email Address')}}
        {{ Form::text('email')}}

        {{ Form::label('username','Username')}}
        {{ Form::text('username')}}

        {{ Form::label('password','Password')}}
        {{ Form::password('password')}}

        {{ Form::submit('Sign up')}}

    {{ Form::close()}}
```

But I have get raw `html` form on bowser window with `html` tags i.e form not created

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5 the blades changed. You need to use `{!! !!}` if you want to post unescaped text

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'register')) !!}
    {!! Form::label('email','Email Address') !!}
    {!! Form::text('email') !!}

    {!! Form::label('username','Username') !!}
    {!! Form::text('username') !!}

    {!! Form::label('password','Password') !!}
    {!! Form::password('password') !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Sign up') !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: have not turned to L5 yet. But the code looks neater while I need to type more !...